# Triple Gaussian integrals in Python

Tags: programming

I need to apply scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.cdf(), which computes the integral

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}\det(\Sigma)}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\right) dx$$,

where $\mu$ is the mean and $\Sigma^{-1}$ is the inverse matrix of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

For my own understanding I am trying to run the same calculation in another program (Maple). Let

\Sigma =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}

and for the purpose of this computation let $a_{11} = a_{22} = a_{33} = 1; a_{12} = a_{21} = 0.87055, a_{13} = a_{31} = 0.710804075, a_{23} = a_{32} = 0.8165$.

If we expand the term in the exponential, we get

$$-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) = -\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{(y - 0.87055 x)^2}{2(1 - 0.87055^2)} - \frac{(z - 0.8165 y)^2}{2(1 - 0.8165^2)}$$

and so the integral I am trying to evaluate in Maple is:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{1.37824} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{-21.58961} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{18.48617} \frac{\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{(y - 0.87055 x)^2}{2(1 - 0.87055^2)} - \frac{(z - 0.8165 y)^2}{2(1 - 0.8165^2)} \right)}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{(1-0.87055^2)(1-0.8165^2)}} dz dy dx$$.

The result is $4.164024864\times10^{-242}$.

Applying scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.cdf() with $[x, y, z] = [1.37824, -21.58961, 18.48617]$, $mean=None$ and $cov=np.array([[1, 0.87055, 0.710804075], [0.87055, 1, 0.8165], [0.710804075, 0.8165, 1]])$.

The result inPython is $1.124512788731174 \times 10^{-103}$.

The difference between the two results is significant. Apparently I am doing something wrong. I will appreciate if anyone can point where my mistake is! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The difference is really, really small?

Comment: You should compare the two probabilities in a region where they have sufficient mass. That upper limit of -21.58961 is too extreme in the negative. Try a selection of $[x,y,z]$ where the variables are between $-3$ and $+3\,.$ I would also try different values of the $a_{ij}\,.$

Comment: @Bob Jansen, the difference is infinitesimal, indeed. But my expectation is that the two outputs should be close. However, it turns out that the powers of 10 are significant.

Comment: @Kurt G, I tried with the standard case (which can be even computed by hand), i.e. when $[x, y, z] = [0, 0, 0]$ and when the covariance matrix is

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},

i.e., $a_{ij}$ is $1$, when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise, then Python and Maple yield $\frac{1}{8}$, which seems to be as expected. That only boosted the impression that I am doing something wrong.
In any case, thank you both for your help!

Comment: Ok. Python and Maple are spot on for 0,0,0 and uncorrelated. The extrem example in your question above leads to zero for Python and Maple. Every numercial practitioner knows that numbers like that are to be treated as zero. You will even get answers with larger differences of orders 1E-15 if you do the calculation on different types of CPUs. Don't worry be happy.

Comment: @Kurt G, thank you for this insight!
Honestly, I’m not experienced with numerical computations. I did spend some time investigating this difference, as I thought there is something I misunderstand or do wrong. Now I can move forward. You saved me a lot of future efforts.

Comment: @Kurt G, I disagree your statement. Different cpus should implement the spec in the same way and give the same result. The floating point epsilon is not some number within which calculations become random, it's just something to be aware of from a rounding perspective. Different implementations however (ie maple vs python) and now it becomes relevant. Same implementation on two different (but still standards compliant) cpus should give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both values are practically zero and the difference between the two pieces of software is really, really small (almost infinitesimal compared to your inputs). Computers are not perfect calculators and some rounding error is to be expected. Try to be aware that they can happen and check whether the rounding error matters for your application.

Comment: Thank you @Bob Jansen! You are totally right, now I realise that the two outputs don't necessarily need to be the same (although they are practically zero, as the comments above imply).